# 403 Forbidden when post request with unEscape html content in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, http

403 error when this type data save.
**this problem is only Namecheap server**

[image: 403 error when this type data save]

when save then result in this
[image: 403 error when save data]

**but without unEscape HTML content  data save successfully **
[image: sucessfully saved this type data]

data seve with unEscape HTML content.

.................. **/admin/page/update** route point code below

```
public function update(Request $request)
{

    $input = $request->all();

    $content = $request->except(['page_code', 'status', '_token']);

    $pageCode = $input['page_code'];
    $page = Page::where('code', $pageCode)->first();

    if ($page->type == 'dynamic') {
        $content = [
            'section_id' => $input['section_id'] ?? null,
            'meta_keywords' => $input['meta_keywords'],
            'meta_description' => $input['meta_description'],
            'content' => Purifier::clean(htmlspecialchars_decode($input['content'])),
        ];

        $data = [
            'title' => $input['title'],
            'data' => json_encode($content),
            'status' => $input['status'],
        ];

    } else {

        $oldData = json_decode($page->data, true);
        foreach ($content as $key => $value) {

            if (is_file($value)) {
                $oldValue = Arr::get($oldData, $key);
                $content[$key] = self::imageUploadTrait($value, $oldValue);

            } elseif ($key == 'content') {
                $content[$key] = Purifier::clean(htmlspecialchars_decode($value));
            }
        }

        $content = array_merge($oldData, $content);

        $data = [
            'status' => $input['status'] ?? true,
            'data' => json_encode($content)
        ];

    }

    $page->update($data);

    if ($page->type == 'dynamic') Cache::pull('pages');

    notify()->success($page->title . ' ' . __(' Updated 
       Successfully'));
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: 403
Forbidden
Access to this resource on the server is denied!

Comment: So ... screenshot your 403 error instead of your textarea. To which route are you posting? Post the route. Post the function in the controller you're using. Show your network tab, Post the form, show the (red) error message, then screenshot that message. Same goes for the console of your browser

Comment: update network error

Comment: Post the `admin/page/update` route in your web.php and then the function it points to, usually an `update` function in a controller. Think a little for yourself here and don't wait till people are saying "post this!, post that!" Whe need to see the text of your function, not a screenshot

Comment: code update . but route not action when with unEscape content ..

Comment: route successfully action when  with Textarea  plain text

Comment: ok, same steps. Go to network tab, post with the nice textArea, so you're getting the 403 error. In the Network tab, go to "response", screenshot that.
Also: Go to the console tab and screenshot that after you get your 403 error

Comment: contact Namecheap support